# Adding columns in a dataframe based on having the same name

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(c(3, 4, 5, 4, 3), c(6, 6, 6, 5, 5), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(9, 8, 9, 9, 7), c(6, 7, 8, 7, 6), c(0, 1, 2, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3), c(5, 5, 5, 5, 4))
colnames(df) <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
> df
  A A A B B B C C C
1 3 6 1 9 6 0 1 3 5
2 4 6 1 8 7 1 1 3 5
3 5 6 1 9 8 2 1 3 5
4 4 5 1 9 7 1 1 2 5
5 3 5 1 7 6 1 1 3 4
```

I would like to add rows that have the same column name and get the following dataframe as a result:

```
> new_df
   A  B C
1 10 15 9
2 11 16 9
3 12 19 9
4 10 17 8
5  9 14 8
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) split.default**  Split the columns into a list of data frames and apply `rowSums` to each.  Then convert back to data.frame.

```
as.data.frame(lapply(split.default(df, names(df)), rowSums))

   A  B C
1 10 15 9
2 11 16 9
3 12 19 9
4 10 17 8
5  9 14 8
```

**2) tapply** Unravel the elements into a vector column by column and use `tapply` to sum over the elements having the same row number and column name.  Finally convert to data frame.

```
as.data.frame(tapply(c(unlist(df)), list(c(row(df)), names(df)[col(df)]), sum))
```

giving:

```
   A  B C
1 10 15 9
2 11 16 9
3 12 19 9
4 10 17 8
5  9 14 8
```

**3) model.matrix** Use `model.matrix` to create a matrix which when premultiplied by `as.matrix(df)` gives the result.  Finally convert to data.frame.

```
mm <- model.matrix(~ names(df) + 0)
setNames(as.data.frame(as.matrix(df) %*% mm), unique(names(df)))
```

giving:

```
   A  B C
1 10 15 9
2 11 16 9
3 12 19 9
4 10 17 8
5  9 14 8
```

**4) by row**  Create a function which performs the summation for one row and then apply it to every row.  Convert to data.frame.

```
collapseRow <- function(x) tapply(x, names(df), FUN = sum)
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, collapseRow)))
```

giving:

```
   A  B C
1 10 15 9
2 11 16 9
3 12 19 9
4 10 17 8
5  9 14 8
```